# how to show jquery function result automatically with any key event

Tags: jquery

Following code of jquery running fine, but it calculates percentage after pressing 'calculate percentage' button. i want it to modify that when user enter second number and press tab, the result will automatically display in third column.

```js
function ShowPercentage() {

  var $inputs = $('input');

  // get values
  var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();
  var SecondNumVal = $inputs.eq(1).val();

  // compute something
  var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;

  // set value
  $inputs.eq(2).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#computeSomething').on('keypress', ShowPercentage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"> <br> mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"> <br> mypercenttextbox
<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox "><br>
<button id="computeSomething">Compute Percentage!</button>
```

Comment: Bind change event to second input i.e. `$('#mysecondnumber').on('change blur', ShowPercentage);`

Comment: @Satpal thanks alot! worked for me

Comment: @Satpal I want to fix second number as constant say 20 and first number will be entered by user, can you please help.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can set its value using `.val(20)` and make it readonly i.e. `.prop('readonly', true)`

Comment: @Satpal unable to implement..can you please share the exact code, i also want to remove inputbox for second number. User will be able to enter only first number..thanks!

Comment: Add working snippet in answer

Comment: @Satpal I have answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `change` event handler to second input `#mysecondnumber` element

```
$('#mysecondnumber').on('change', ShowPercentage);
```

```js
function ShowPercentage() {

  var $inputs = $('input');

  // get values
  var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();
  var SecondNumVal = $inputs.eq(1).val();

  // compute something
  var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;

  // set value
  $inputs.eq(2).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#computeSomething').on('keypress', ShowPercentage);
  $('#mysecondnumber').on('change', ShowPercentage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"> <br> mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"> <br> mypercenttextbox
<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox "><br>
<button id="computeSomething">Compute Percentage!</button>
```

Make second text box, readonly and set value as `20`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $inputs = $('input');
  $('#mysecondnumber').val(20).prop('readonly', true).prop('disabled', true);

  function ShowPercentage() {
    // get values
    var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();
    var SecondNumVal = $inputs.eq(1).val();

    // compute something
    var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;

    // set value
    $inputs.eq(2).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');
  }

  $('#computeSomething').on('keypress', ShowPercentage);
  $('#myfirstnumber').on('change', ShowPercentage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"> <br> mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"> <br> mypercenttextbox
<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox "><br>
<button id="computeSomething">Compute Percentage!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"> <br>

<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"> <br>

<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox "><br>
<button id="computeSomething">Compute Percentage!</button>
<script>
function ShowPercentage() {

    var $inputs = $('input');

    // get values
    var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();
    var SecondNumVal = $inputs.eq(1).val(20).prop('readonly', true);

    // compute something
    var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;

    // set value
    $inputs.eq(2).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%').prop('readonly', true);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mysecondnumber').on('change blur', ShowPercentage);
});
```